# How can i add hover effect to buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me out. I really need to create an button effect for the img buttons i created. Is there a css solution are do i need to create other buttons? I hope anyone can help me because i really need an effect.

```
<html><head>  

    <title>Mobiel</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><!-- Bootstrap -->  

    <link href="css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\styles_responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <style>  
    body {  
    padding: 50px  
    }  
    </style><!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries --><!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// --><!--[if lt IE 9]>  
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>  
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>  
    <![endif]-->  


<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
  var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
  msViewportStyle.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(
      "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
    )
  );
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
    appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
</script>

  <style>
 .navbar {
 position: left;    
 overflow: visible;   
 padding-top: 0;
 }   
 </style>
 <style type="text/css">
li{list-style-type:none;float:left;}
 a{text-align:center}
</style>

</head>  
  <body>  

 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">

<img src="img\Logo_helpen.jpg" alt="Logo"></div></div></div>
<p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
<br>
<a href="#"><img src="img\hoe-werkt-het.png" alt="Hoe werkt het?" name="Hoe werkt het?" class="img-rounded">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<a href="search\index.html"><img src="img\smoelenboek.png" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="alert\alert.html"><img src="img\aagje-alert.png" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded"></a></p><p>
<small>Hoe werkt&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; Smoelenboek &nbsp; &nbsp;Aagje Alert <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; het? &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small><br>
<img src="img\alert.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<img src="img\alert.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="img\alert.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded"></a></p>
<br><a href="#">
<img src="img\alert.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="img\alert.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<img src="img\alert.jpg" alt="image with rounded corners" class="img-rounded"></a><p><a href="#">  


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->  
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>  
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->  
    <script src="js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
 </a></p></body></html>
```

Comment: Just use `:hover` quite simple. Questions though, why do you have so many style tags in your html? And why are there so many `&nbsp;`s?

Comment: Having multiple style or script tags usualy indicates that different bits of code has come from different sources (not a bad thing), and it should not really make any difference to the site.

Comment: @SamDenton it doesn't but it makes your code dirty and difficult to read. Organize all your css inside an external file is far better and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make code simpler... put the images in CSS:

```
a .img-rounded{
    background-image: url("image.png");
}
```

Use `:hover` for for hovering:

```
a .img-rounded:hover {
    background-image: url("hover.png");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the CSS properties of an element on hover use `:hover` in your CSS.

```
a .img-rounded:hover {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well this could help you

```
<style>

a.img-rounded {
display:block;
height:10px;
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.img-rounded:hover {
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 -10px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an text overlay hover effect.

Comment: The only way i can think to add a text overlay onhover would be to have a div hidden or behind which contains the text, and when you hover, it becomes visible

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to change styling like borders with css onhover, as shown by other answers, your best bet is to create another button wich you wish to be the hover over, and add in

```
onmouseover="this.src='hovereffect.jpg'"
```

and

```
onmouseout="this.src='origenal.jpg'"
```

to your inline stylings on the button you wich to change when hovering over.

Note - The best on hover effects tend to be simple like the text contained gaining a shadow or 3d effect.

Comment: It works fine but I wouldn't use it becasue if javascript is disabled for the user... it won't work. (Although, most people should have javascript enabled)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work with the html part because i have different png files for every button. I need just an simple hover effect.

Comment: Was this ment to be a comment?  If so, who's answer was it for?